# MapView.onPause hangs in Google Maps API v2 for Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a `Fragment` (from the support library) which includes a `MapView` (from the Google Maps API v2). When an info window belonging to a marker is clicked, I want to switch from the `Fragment` containing the `MapView` to another `Fragment` containing the details about the place represented by the marker. In order to switch, I use this code:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(oldFragment)
  .add(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, tag)
  .addToBackStack(null)
  .commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

The problem is that, after clicking an info window, the application hangs. I was able to step through with a debugger, only to find that the ultimate cause is a call to `Object.wait()` inside the Google Maps API v2 library triggered by `MapView.onPause()`, which I must call as per `MapView` documentation.

I have also tried to comment out the `onPause()` call, but another `Object.wait()` is triggered from another method inside the Google Maps API v2 library, and the application still hangs. I also tried to put a whole `MapFragment` in place of the `MapView`, but nothing changes.

I wasn't able to find anyone with this very same problem, so I'm pretty much lost. Any idea of what is going on, what I'm doing wrong, and what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: If you can create simple example and are certain it is something wrong in the Maps v2 implementation, I suggest posting on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation, the culprit seems to be the call to `executePendingTransactions()`, or the way it interacts with `MapView`/`MapFragment`. When that call is removed, the application stops hanging.